# Which event is fired when we hide/show a column in ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need a event which is fired when we hide/show a column in ui-grid.
Is there some internal flag which can be used for persisting the state(visible/hidden) for a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
columnVisibilityChanged(scope, callBack)
```

check out the [api and its example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi)

Comment: Hi asqan i tried using this function but it throws an error on console(something like cannot find property of undefined).
Do i need to include some external script other than normal ui-grid.js file?

Comment: no you dont have to. try the following and let me know what error you take: `$scope.gridAPI.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged = function(){ console.log(test); }`
Also, check the documentation if you need to know how to use gridApi

Comment: works but after a bit of alteration...   async working of angularjs was the issue leading to error  found the solution here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1774
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ 
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
       $scope.gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged( $scope,function (column){ console.log("Hi..."); });
     }